# Using awk, is there a simple way to group fields with spaces

Tags: awk

I have a file that has data like this:

```
New York  100 2 17 12
California 200 10 8 3
Montana   50 25  3 0
```

I want the state name to be treated as a single field, then calculate what percent of field 2 is field 3, and ignore the other fields.

So I'd like the output to be

```
New York  2%
California 5%
Montana   50%
```

I can obtain the state name thusly `awk -F [0-9]  '{print $1}'`

but then the rest of the fields are completely unusable.

If I leave the field separator alone, New and York get separate field numbers, and the other field numbers are 'off by one'.

Can I do this in awk, or should I switch to ruby, which I know a little bit?

Comment: Is the white space in your example all blank characters or is some of it tabs? No, you should not switch to Ruby.

Comment: All white space, no tabs.

Comment: white space includes horizontal tabs, vertical tabs, blanks, linefeeds, formfeeds, etc. I think what you probably meant is "all blanks, no tabs or other white space".

Comment: yes, all "space" character.  ASCII 32.  Sorry about the bad nomenclature

Comment: Yeah, it's annoying and unfortunate that the words "blank" and "space" have so many different meanings. I tend to think in terms of a `blank character` is ASCII 32 (often represented in code by `" "`), a `blank` is any of the set of chars in the `[:blank:]` POSIX character class (often represented in code by `\b`) and a `space` is any of the set of chars in the `[:space:]` POSIX character class (often represented in code by `\s`). See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Bracket-Expressions, for example, for a definition of the characters in those character classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it fairly easily in `awk`. The trick is the find the first field that begins with a digit so you can accommodate names like `"New York"`. For example

```
awk '{
    n=0; name=""
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        if($i ~ /^[0-9]/) {
            n=i; break
        }
        else
            name=name?name" "$i:$i
    print name, $(n+1)/$n*100"%"
}' file
```

Where the variable `n` is used to capture the field-number for the first field beginning with a digit by looping over each field and comparing the first character to `[0-9]`. If the test is true, `n` is set to `i` and the loop is broken, otherwise the character field is concatenated with `name`.. (this assumes you have 2 fields with numbers)

You can just select-copy the script above and then middle-mouse paste into an xterm in the directory holding your file (after you change the filename to match your data file) Putting it together with your data, you would get:

```
$ awk '{
>     n=0; name=""
>     for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
>         if($i ~ /^[0-9]/) {
>             n=i; break
>         }
>         else
>             name=name?name" "$i:$i
>     print name, $(n+1)/$n*100"%"
> }' file
New York 2%
California 5%
Montana 50%
```

Comment: Can you explain how this line works?   name=name?name" "$i:$i

Comment: Sure, `name` is just the name of the State. To handle multiple words in a state name, we start off with an empty `name=""`. Then we loop over the fields `for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)`. If the field begins with a number `/^[0-9]/` we have found the first number field, otherwise if it does not begin with a number, we know it is part of the name and concatenate the field with the name `name = name ? name" "$i : $i`. The `test ? if_true : if_false` clause is called a *ternary* operator. If `name` (means not empty) `?` then we add a space and current field `name" "$i`, otherwise just add first `$i`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the last field as a reference point. Requires gawk/mawk for discarding the last four fields:

```
$ awk '{p=$(NF-2)*100/$(NF-3); NF-=4; print ($0"\t"p"%")}' file
New York   2%
California 5%
Montana    50%
```

And the portable alternative to that is:

```
awk '{p=$(NF-2)*100/$(NF-3); sub(/( +[^ ]+){4}$/,""); print ($0"\t"p"%")}' file
```

Comment: Okay, that's pretty clever counting backwards `:)` Only downside is you are stuck with that number of fields -- but normally that's not a problem.

Comment: @David what actually bothers me is that decreasing NF produce undefined results according to the standard. Thanks btw

Comment: What if you used `NF > 5` and then `split` the record into an array and then took the first `NF - 4` fields as the name and the next 2 to calculate the percentage?. (I like that better than my first guess too)

Comment: @David that'd require building the first field by joining `NF - 4` fields in a loop and thus wouldn't be a one-liner. Good idea though, if you care to add that to your answer as an alternative solution I'll definitely upvote

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there's always a fixed number of fields at the end, you can use that information to adjust the fields on the fly as per the following transcript:

```
pax> echo; printf 'New York 100 2 17 12\nCalifornia 200 10 8 3\nMontana 50 25 3 0\n' | awk '
+++> {while(NF>5){$1=$1" "$2;for(i=2;i<NF;i++){$i=$(i+1)};$NF="";NF=NF-1};print $1","$2","$3","$4}'

New York,100,2,17
California,200,10,8
Montana,50,25,3
```

You can see by the `,` separators that field 1 has been combined from the two fields `New` and `York`. Examining that script in detail:

```
while (NF > 5) {                 # Loop until entire name combined into field 1.
    $1 = $1" "$2                 # Join field 1 and 2.
    for (i = 2; i < NF; i++) {   # For every field 2 onward.
        $i = $(i+1)              # Copy following field to this field,
    }                            #     includes blanking last field.
    NF = NF - 1                  # Reduce field count.
}
# At this point field1 is whole name and fields 2-5 are values.
```